# Gorilla WebSocket WriteMessage errors - Go Lang

Tags: go, error-handling, websocket, gorilla

I am currently experimenting with Gorilla WebSocket package. When sending a message using [`WriteMessage`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage), if an error is returned, what should I do? Should I start the [Closing Handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.2) or assume that if there is a problem it will be caught using the [`ReadMessage`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.ReadMessage) method and simply log the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If WriteMessage returns an error, then the application should close the connection. This releases resources used by the connection and causes the reader to return with an error.

It is not possible to send a closing handshake after WriteMessage returns an error. If WriteMessage returns an error, then all subsequent writes will also return an error.